# Create Button Array

Tags: c#, winforms

I have 25 buttons on winform.I want add buttons to array with this way :

```
**Button btn =(Button)(this.Controls.Find("button"+i,true)[0]);** //this is hint
```

I tried this but it didnt work.When ı changed index [0] at the end of code ı get out of range exception:

```
Button[] button = new Button[25];

        for(int i = 0; i < 25; i++)
        {
            button[i] = (Button)(this.Controls.Find("button" + i, true)[0]);
        }
```

How can ı use this hint ?

Comment: Show where you named your controls and added them to the form.

Comment: if you added your buttons with designer, the button name will start with `button1`, so your `i` should start with `1` instead of  `0`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change the index of your for loop and re-test. As stated by `ViperLiu` in comment, the reason of out-of-index error is because the button is named automatically by Visual Studio starting from "button1"

```
Button[] button = new Button[25];

for(int i = 0; i < 25; i++)
{
    button[i] = (Button)(this.Controls.Find("button" + (i + 1), true)[0]);
}
```